# Battlefield - Board Game Strategy

Tags: algorithm, matrix

Consider a square matrix, all slots filled with zeroes.This will be the battlefield. Now, to place ships, I indicate the by putting 1. A ship can be of size 1, 2, 3 - meaning two or three continuous blocks should be 1. They can also be horizontal or vertical. Now , what is the best strategy for an enemy to search for my ships. He has no idea how I have placed my ships. What could be a good strategy to search the matrix ? OR How do I make the CPU a better player when it comes to making 'smart moves' ?

1. Search randomly
2. Search, and when you find one attack the neighbouring blocks to check if it size 2/3 ship.
3. Also, the initial positioning of the CPU can be based on the previous winning positions and not just based on  random numbers.
4. Any other idea ..... ??

The idea can be extended to form a larger board game of 20 x 20 matrix with multiple ships.An example is given below.

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
```

Any help would be much appreciated !!

Comment: Just made necessary edits - thanks @bytefire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have a ship with a size of 1, you basically need to enumerate through all of the fields and check the neighbors for bigger ships. You can save some work by using specific order like going through all of the rows:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 10 11 12
13 ...
```

If you have to detect bigger ships, you check the following two right fields (if not out of bounds; you check the first field and if it's a part of a ship, then you check the second) as well of the two bottom fields (again boundary check). Using that traversal you ensure that you never check the left and the top fields for bigger ship. When you check for bigger ships, you should remember how many positions you have visited right and skip those after moving along.

It's just a suggestion and is relatively efficient one. With some memory usage you can avoid double visiting fields after checking bottom, but this won't lead to a performance win in the real life.

Comment: Thanks @Ivaylo Toskov.  Yes , I have done this implementation by enumerating the squares like this. It is indeed an improvement over naive methods. But I am looking to make use of some data structure to really improve the performance. I fell I am still missing out on something really efficient.

Comment: There is no way to considerably boost the performance. This is due to the fact that you have single-fielded ships, which basically means that you need to enumerate through all of the fields and there is no 'super efficient' method to do that apart from such small adjustments. In fact using a data structure could actually worse the performance, as you will have to check for each field if it's in the data structure, wheres you can basically do that for the neighbors, but only for some of the fields.

Comment: Sounds valid. Any suggestions on how to make the CPU player smarter ? I mean , allowing it to guess better, in a more calculated manner ?

Comment: Implement the algorithm suggested for it. I don't know which programming language you are using to give you further tips.